# Suppose $m/l$ is a root of $f$, where $m$ and $l$ are relatively prime integers. Show that $m$ divides $a_0$ and $l$ divides $a_n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, divisibility, roots

Suppose $f(x) = a_nx^n + \dots + a_1x + a_0$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients, and suppose $m/l$ is a root of $f$, where $m$ and $l$ are relatively prime integers. Show that $m$ divides $a_0$ and $l$ divides $a_n$.

I know for an $m/l$ to be a root of a $f$ it must satisfy $f(m/l) = a_n(m/l)^n + \dots + a_1(m/l) + a_0 = 0$

I also know for $m$ and $l$ to be relatively prime their greatest common divisor must be $1$.

And $m$ divides $a_0$ and $l$ divides $a_n$ if there is some nonconstant $h$ such that $a_0 = mh$ and $a_n = lh$

However, I'm getting stuck on how to approach this problem. All help is appreciated!

Comment: To cancel all $l$ factors in denominators, what should be the multiplier?  What is the resulting function?

Comment: Hint: multiply by $l^{n}$ to get an expression involving integers only. Reduce modulo $l$; what do you find? Reduce modulo $m$ to deduce something similar.

Comment: Divide the equality in the second line by $m$ first to get $m|a_0$.